# display for loop variable in a table having a loop from the db

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to iterating over a loop from the database that selects displays only seven records from the database table. So I want to index this records from 1 to 7 using additional for loop as shown in the snippet

```
 <?php foreach ($tips as $tips) { ?>
    <?php
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 7; $x++) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $x; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tips->tips; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

my challenge is that the records are not indexed from 1 to 7 as the values iterates and the first record from the db table only displays on the last index which is 7. Is there a way I can go around this to achieve this result. kindly assist

Comment: try my solution it will help you

Comment: *"`foreach($tips as $tips)`"* -- it gets the first value from `$tips` and puts it in `$tips`; this way it overwrites the original list and breaks the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code.

```
$x = 1;
<?php foreach($tips as $tip){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $x; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $tip; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php $x++; } ?>
```

Comment: @parker happy to help you :)